# `.~lock.myfile.jpg#` Windows 7 photos corrupted/locked

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery

I'm facing this problem where all photos in this specific folder (over 700) are named `.~lock.myfile.jpg#` and `.~lock.myfile.doc#`.

Windows can't recognize nor open these files.

How can I rescue or "unlock" my files?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PC has been/was infected with malware.

Refer [here](http://forum.bittorrent.com/topic/5886-all-my-files-are-renamed-locked/), and [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/Something-Locked-Files-Renamed-and-maybe-encrypted-on-Windows-7), and [this.](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/539666/files-renamed-to-locked/)

Honestly I'd suggest you to reinstall Windows with a clean installation disk as ***it's no longer worthwhile to even attempt to remove malware from an installed operating system.*** If you already have a backup (100% clean) that's even better. **However** if you feel that you don't care if your information/passwords etc are stolen and are willing to take the risk, you can follow the steps in another superuser question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc).

Remember to assume that your current Antivirus has already been infected!

After all of that is done and you are 100% sure that there are no more malware on your computer, then you may now attempt to unlock the files using Dr Web or Panda - keep in mind that if won't always succeed.

**Symptoms**

> My computer has been infected by a virus and now files with extensions
>   such as .exe, .doc or .pdf have been renamed as
>   locked-nameofthefile.ext.xxxx (where xxxx are random characters) and
>   no longer work. Finally follow the instructions to unlock the files
>   [here](http://www.pandasecurity.com/newzealand/homeusers/support/card?id=1675).

[Here's](http://forums.digitalspy.co.uk/showthread.php?t=1658059) another user in your situation - he solved it.

After this remember to keep a backup of all your files!